# What is the preferred way of transfering a filesystem between two local HDD's

Tags: filesystem, backup, transfer

I want to migrate an external USB HDD which I have been running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS for a while onto a Laptop internal HDD.

Unfortunately the internal HDD is smaller than the external HDD so I cannot transfer the partition using dd. But all the files on the external HDD will fit on the internal HDD so copying all files will work.

After googling and reading [this blog post](http://jeremy.zawodny.com/blog/archives/010037.html) and all its comments, it seems like rsync -H and cp -a are both good candidates, but I never really got a confirming answer which of those that was fastest, most reliable etc. rsync is good for other things as well but for a local filesystem transfer, cp would be the right choice, I mean this is Unix so the basic commands should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rsync is meant for regularly synchronizing two copies and efficiently transferring only the changed parts.  Since you only need to copy once, cp -a will work just fine, though you should get the same results with rsync.

After copying, you will need to edit /etc/fstab on the internal disk and update the UUID of the disk.  You can look up your disks' UUIDs with:

```
sudo blkid
```

Then you will need to install grub on the internal disk.  Assuming that the internal disk is sda and you have it mounted in /mnt, do:

```
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt/ /dev/sda
```

That will make the new disk bootable.

Comment: Thanks, I read your answer too-late, I took the tedious route and  did mount dev/sys/proc & chroot /mnt prior running grub-install. It worked but the --root-directory is more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

When doing a selective backup, make sure that you copy /var/cache/apt/archives to your new machine. This way, you do not need to re-download all packages.